# Include reactive filter to reactor chain

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a Flux of objects, and I need to filter them using a reactive method. Since `filter` does not support reactive type, how can I reach this?

```
Flux<Student> students = ...
students
  .filter(this::leavesNearby)
  .collectList();  


Mono<Boolean> leavesNearby(Student student) {
   Address address = student.getAddress;    
   return addressService.isNearby(address);
}
```

Considering `addressService.isNearby(address)` returns `Mono<Boolean>`, I have a compilation error on this line `filter(this::leavesNearby)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filterWhen`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#filterWhen-java.util.function.Function-):

```java
students
  .filterWhen(this::leavesNearby)
  .collectList();
```